Does torchlibrosa or librosa perform better for realtime audio processing?
I'm looking at doing some realtime audio processing (more specifically pitch shifting) - does Librosa or Torchlibrosa (https://github.com/qiuqiangkong/torchlibrosa) perform better at this in Python or what are some good benchmarks or algorithms to test this?
I know that Python isn't naturally suited to realtime applications, but I need to for this project. I am unsure of how to benchmark it quantitatively.

What latency requirements are there?

It's a live music thing, so as low as possible.

That is not really a requirement. There are diminishing returns on benefits of lower latency. And there are algorithmic and I/O sources of latency that may overwhelm the processing ones. To be able to realize an actual system, you want as high as possible budget... For real-time the budget must be hit every single time. So there is a natural tradeoff.

Benchmarking of real-time systems is done by measuring to which degree the system is able to meet the real-time deadline, including under adverse conditions.
For a basic audio system, the main deadline is given by the audio I/O subsystem, which has a callback with a fixed size audio buffers - containing the input and output. The processing may also use internal buffers, potentially flexible buffering such as a queue/FIFO. If the processing is not able to fill the output buffer in time, it has failed to meet the deadline (buffer underrun).
So, benchmarking a real-time audio system means selecting a set of buffer sizes, running it and counting how many failures to meet deadline. It is good to run the tests for a set of buffer sizes / latency values, to determine where the problems get critical. If the system is not dedicated 100% to the audio processing, one must also test with other computational loads running at the same time, since this will be a major influence.
With this methodology, you will be able to answer which of the two libraries work best for your particular use-case and system.

It looks like torchlibrosa is simply a recreation of librosa that can run on a GPU using pytorch, which is only useful if you're trying to process massive amounts of data (for example for training a neural network) So maybe a good starting question is, is your real-time project going to be running on a GPU? If not, then it probably makes sense to go with regular librosa.
If you need a benchmark, you can find loads of examples online on benchmarking a python function in a short script. See how long the function you want takes using torchlibrosa, then do the same for the same function using librosa, and compare the times.

GPU adds a source of latency, in particular the CPU to GPU communication. For low latency real-time applications, this may void the benefits of additional FLOPS on the GPU, or even increase risks of missing the deadline and causing audio dropout.
